# Any reference authentication implementation for GRAILS 3.x with new firebase SDK

Tags: grails, spring-security, firebase, firebase-authentication

Are there any reference implementations with grails 3.x and firebase JAVA sdk that google published in may 2016? I have an understanding of grails & have an application running in production on it, however I am not an expert. I have 2 objectives

a) I want to explore the possibility of using JWTs via Firebase for authentication
b) where should I store authorities in firebase or grails application ?

I am hoping it will be as simple as opening another database connection and have the user, role and authority objects mapped to firebase and spring security will work as is in my current application.